# Using VLookup and Excel Tables names in Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting

This VLOOKUP formula works: Matching the name (Resource, Full Name) and returning the Status (10th column in the table)

```
=VLOOKUP(tblResourcePlan[Resource],tblTeamMasterRoster[[Full Name]:[Status]],10,FALSE)
```

But when I use it in Conditional Formatting, it gives me an error - "There is a problem with this formula" - I've tried three different variations:

```
 =VLOOKUP(tblResourcePlan[Resource],tblTeamMasterRoster[[Full Name]:[Status]],10,FALSE) = "Future"

 =VLOOKUP(indirect(tblResourcePlan[Resource]),indirect(tblTeamMasterRoster[[Full Name]:[Status]]),10,FALSE) = "Future"

 =VLOOKUP(H2,indirect(tblTeamMasterRoster[[Full Name]:[Status]]),10,FALSE) = "Future"
```

BTW, Here's a similar formula that works!!

```
=ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,INDIRECT("tblTeamMasterRoster[Full Name]"),1,FALSE)) = TRUE)
```

Please help!

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(indirect("tblResourcePlan[@Resource]"),indirect("tblTeamMasterRoster[[Full Name]:[Status]]"),10,FALSE) = "Future"` don't forget the quotes.

Comment: the Quotes!! :-) . I'll remember them next time!!